# prevent overwriting to WRITE function for char driver linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

My driver must write from the user buffer to a char array called msg, which is in global scope

```
//global scope
...
#define SIZE 64;
char msg[SIZE];
...
```

So this is the write function.

```
static ssize_t  Dev_Write(struct file *flip, const char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset)
    {

        copy_from_user(msg + *offset, buffer, length); //I hope *offset = 0 at the first call
        printk(KERN_INFO "message from UserSpace is: %s \n", msg);
        *offset += length;

        return length;
    }
```

When I invoke this function two times in sequence, it overwrites the first data in msg. I want it just to continue from the last position.
I think I must do something with ***offset**

This is the user program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define BUFFER_SIZE 64

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int fd;
    ssize_t read_bytes;
    ssize_t written_bytes;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = "aaaaaa";
    char buffer1[BUFFER_SIZE] = "bbbbbb";
    char buffer2[BUFFER_SIZE];
    fd = open ("/dev/2", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Cannot open file\n");
        exit (1);
    }   


    written_bytes = write (fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    write (fd, buffer1, BUFFER_SIZE);
    read_bytes = read (fd, buffer2, BUFFER_SIZE);
    cout<<buffer<<endl;
    if(written_bytes < 0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "myread: Cannot write to file\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    if (read_bytes < 0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "myread: Cannot read from file\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    close (fd);
    exit (0);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear about what you're doing. When you say "I invoke this function two times in sequence" do you mean your kernel mode calls it twice asynchronously? Or in respond to one call from user-space? Or in response to two calls from userspace? We have no context to understand your question, having no idea what your write function is for or what your device driver drives.

Comment: You're right. Sorry. It respond on call from userspace. In my user program I write to a file which is in **/dev** and which is bind to my device with it's major number. This is simple char device driver. And after two write functions in userspace my driver Dev_Write function overwrites the data, instead of continue it.

Comment: Then the problem is likely that user space is passing the same buffer twice.

Comment: I pass two different buffers. for example 
`char b1[size] = "aaaa" 
char b2[size] = "bbbb" `
and in kernel space I recieve **message from UserSpace is: aaaa 
                              message from UserSpace is: bbbb**
but instead of that i want    **message from UserSpace is: aaaa 
                              message from UserSpace is: aaaabbbb**

Comment: It sounds like you have some trivial bug in your driver. Either you're copying the new data on top of the old rather than after it, or you are looking at the beginning of the second write instead of the beginning of the buffer. Just debug your code. Where is `offset` coming from? What passes it to this function?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `offset` comes from the Linux VFS: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c#L420

Comment: Can you post the source of your user-space sequence, so we can check for mistakes there?

Comment: Does the function that calls `DevWrite` save the modified offset by calling `file_pos_write`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - as this is a Linux kernel driver, then `sys_write` calls `file_pos_write`: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c#L488

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem.

I had to add to *offset the real length of data in buffer.

```
copy_from_user(msg + *offset, buffer, length); 
printk(KERN_INFO "message from UserSpace is: %s \n", msg);
*offset += strlen(buffer);
```

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2):

While the root problem isn't entirely clear, you do have a bug that's pushing you into undefined behaviour. Your user space program is writing 64 bytes (`BUFFER_SIZE`) each time, but your kernel buffer is only 64 bytes long. The second write will cause an overflow.

To debug your problems, take the following steps. At the entry to your write function debug the length and offset of your message:

```
printk(KERN_INFO "Size from userspace is: %d offset %d\n", length, *offset);
```

Also, clamp your copy size so you don't overwrite the buffer:

```
if (*offset > SIZE)
    return -ENOSPC;
if (*offset + length > SIZE)
    length = SIZE - *offset;
```

After these tests you can carry out your `copy_from_user`. The tests are necessary, but I'm not sure that they are a sufficient fix. The debug line may reveal that something else is confounding the situation.

Answer (score 1):

> I think I must do something with *offset

Yes, you indeed ought to. That is to say, you can ignore setting the file position if your driver does not have a concept of file position (like a pipe or socket). And to be able to set this file position, `offset` is a pointer, so that you can modify the value such that it is visible outside. (You also need a lot more safety checks in your code to assure you don't write past the end of the buffer.) `*offset += whatever` is just right. Note that the file offset need not be measured in bytes, you can also count in "records" or whatever else floats your boats.